# Eclipse and Appengine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, servlets

I have been using Appengine to try and work with the Google+ API. Unfortunately, Appengine has not worked since I began working on my project. Recently, I ran into a major problem when attempting to run an application based off of the following tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVIIgcIqoPw. The error is as follows: An error occurred for ClassEnhancer "ASM" when trying to call the method "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/appengine/tools/enhancer/Enhance : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0". I received the error after trying to "clean" the project in Eclipse.

Here is the current code I am using:

```
package com.example.myproject;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.plus.Plus;
import com.google.api.services.plus.PlusRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.plus.model.Activity;
import com.google.api.services.plus.model.ActivityFeed;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PlusBasicServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyBggyzruOQtog0A6HDlrxGvK2JdLV5ihNE";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport  = new UrlFetchTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        Plus plus = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null).setApplicationName("").setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new     PlusRequestInitializer(API_KEY)).build();
        ActivityFeed myActivityFeed = plus.activities().search("Google").execute();
        List<Activity> myActivities = myActivityFeed.getItems();

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        resp.setStatus(200);
        Writer writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.write("<url>");
        for(Activity a: myActivities){
            writer.write("<li>" + a.getTitle() + "</li>");
        }
        writer.write("</ul>");

    }
}
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because your using a java version under 1.7.

Run your project with JRE 1.7, and it will be good.

**EDIT**

Google App Engine does not support java 8 yet, as you can see on [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9537).

It's coming soon.

So you have to downgrade your Java environment.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I am currently using JRE 1.8 though so I do not think that is the problem.

Comment: If you follow the video, can you tell me the JRE installed that you have in your Eclipse? (Preferences>Java>Installed JRE)

Comment: I currently have Java 1.8.0 installed.

Comment: Can you give what's those cammand prints in your console : `java -version`and `javac -version`? The error `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`is for sure a java version problem...